# Task Factory is sequential and not parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task, taskfactory

I am not a thread expert but I wanted to run a function N times at once in parallel and if needed using more than one core when available.

I currently have the bellow code:

```
tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < _runThreads; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        GetRSS();
    }, stopAllTasks.Token));
}
```

GetRSS sample:

```
private void GetRSS()
{
    while (!queue.IsEmpty)
    {
        int total = 0;
        // dequeue, get url bla bla
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //some code here get html content
        }
        // parse the rss bla bla
        // get the count of total items found 
        // update total variable with the total

        Interlocked.Add(ref counter, total);
    }
}
```

As you can see, at the GetRSS code I am updating `counter` with the total entries per page it gets, as my timer ticks it updates the value of counter to a label so I can see the progress.

From this, I have noticed that the tasks are not working all at once but they are in fact working 1 by 1 as the counter only updates X amount, that is equivalent to a single function running.

So from there I believe that the above code doesn't actually run the tasks in parallel but they seems to run it in sequence.

- Is that right ?
- If so, how do I convert my code so it will actually run in parallel ?

Comment: No your tasks will run in parallel. Is there another place where `counter` is updated?

Comment: Nope it is only updated from that function and aside from that my timer will read it later to update the label at a 1 second interval.

Comment: Approx how large is your queue?  Are you using development server (assuming web client is hitting your own code)?

Comment: You're accessing the object pointed to by queue unsynchronized. This is a bug that will only rarely manifest itself.

Comment: Unless the queue is a ConcurrentQueue ; )

Comment: Even then it is a race with regard to popping and enqueueing from it.

Comment: I have around 30k pages on the queue and yes it is a ConcurrentQueue that it reads from.

Comment: The pages in the queue target a variety of sites?  Or just one?  A single target could be be restricting concurrent hits.  An example would be an asp.net mvc site that didn't have session set to readonly on it's rss controller (serializes concurrent hits).

Comment: Its a local hosted site and I have a try and catch around my original code so if there is a restriction that would block me from further accessing the pages, it should throw an exception right ? Also I have not run more than 30 threads at total from the tests I've done so far.

Comment: I'm pretty sure development server has restrictions around concurrency as well (not sure if it allows concurrency at all actually).  Are you using development server or IIS?

Comment: No, it won't block you or throw an exception, it will queue if there are too many concurrent hits.

Comment: You should add some logging to see what's actually going on, not just guess. Or just use debugger.

Comment: its an linux server running apache at my home network. @svick indeed, I was actually doing that as we the conversation kept going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should definitely run in parallel. Check out similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7878603/166584).

Also, you might face the connection limit, that's why you could think it runs sequentially. You could use configuration to override that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address="*" maxconnection="<some reasonable number here>" />
        </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I haven't ran more then 10 to 20 threads at a time using win7, so I don't think I've hit the 100 cons, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Incredible, I've debug lots of things and came down to try this and it solved the issue.